# How can I restructure my code for rendering in jinja 2 template?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, mongodb, jinja2

I'm trying to display a values from mongo database in web application. I'm using flask framework where I'm calling function which will return lists to print in a html template. My code is as bellow

```
dic = mycol.find(myquery)
```

This will contents dictionary object querying from mongodatabase

When I loop over this object I get dictionary set

```
for x in dic:
```

like each value of x contains

```
{'name':'john','age':'15','weight':'50'}
{'name':'ash','age':'18','weight':'60'}
{'name':'tim','age':'20','weight':'80'}
```

Code which I'm using for rendering these values as below

```
person_name = []
person_age = []
person_weight = []
for x in dic:
    person_name.append(x["person_name"])
    person_age.append(x["person_age"]) 
    person_weight.append(x["person_weight"])
```

later I'm returning these lists for printing in html 
jinja 2 code  is as below

```
{{person_name[loop.index0]}} {{person_age[loop.index0]}} {{person_weight[loop.index0]}}
```

I feel this is not better approach to do this way. So is there any other better approach to do this in a very few line of code? Thanks for reading

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to restructure it at all. Why not just pass that original list of dicts straight to the template?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using flask you can simply pass a list or dictionary to the HTML template using the render_template() flask function.

In your case you can simply do (using this as an example). Note, where `dictionary=dic` is written, the first `dictionary` can be any name / variable, which you will then reference in the Jinja2 syntax.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Code to get dictionary from db, assigned to dic like yours
    return render_template('[name of template].html', dictionary=dic)
```

Then inside your template you can use Jinja2 syntax to do a for loop to list through the dic dictionary / list.

```
// Somewhere inside HTML template
{% for x in dictionary %}
    <p>{{ x.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ x.age }}</p>
    <p>{{ x.weight }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```